# How can I close twitter web intent once tweet is done by user?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I have used the below script to enable tweet/retweet/favorite tweet post. I need to close the pop up automatically once the action is completed.

I have used Twitter web intent code for this but this is not closing pop up even after action is completed. Is there any way to do same?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            t = window.twttr || {};
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s);
          js.id = id;
          js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
         
          t._e = [];
          t.ready = function(f) {
            t._e.push(f);
          };
         
          return t;
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
         
        // Define our custom event handlers
        function tweetIntentToAnalytics (intentEvent) {
           if (!intentEvent) return;
           window.close();
           window.location.reload();
        }
         
        function favIntentToAnalytics (intentEvent) {
         if (!intentEvent) return;
         window.close();
         window.location.reload();
        }
         
        function retweetIntentToAnalytics (intentEvent) {
          if (!intentEvent) return;
          window.close();
         window.location.reload();
        }
        
        // Wait for the asynchronous resources to load
        twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
          // Now bind our custom intent events
           twttr.events.bind('tweet', tweetIntentToAnalytics);
          twttr.events.bind('retweet', retweetIntentToAnalytics);
          twttr.events.bind('favorite', favIntentToAnalytics);
          });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="action_bot">
     <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=<?php echo $res['id'];?>"><span class="reply"></span></a>
     <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=<?php echo $res['id'];?>"><span class="retweet"><?php echo $res['re_count']; ?></span></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=<?php echo $res['id'];?>"> <span class="favorite"><?php echo $res['fb_count'];?></span></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any messages in the console? What if you replace `window.close()` with `alert('test');`? Are you seeing a popup?

Comment: Yes, It is showing alert message.

Comment: So are you getting any error message in your console of either window when it gets to `window.close()`? I'm assuming that it's trying to close the main window, and not the popup window.

Comment: No this is not showing any error in console

Comment: In the popup or the main page console?

Comment: No it is not showing in both console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78867/discussion-between-shimar-and-frankerz).